# How can I use this UTF 8 shape in css :before { content: }?

Tags: html, css

I am looking at some shapes here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp

For example, if I want to use this one:

`◹  9721    25F9        UPPER RIGHT TRIANGLE`, how do I do that?

Do i just copy the icon and put it in the css file, or do I use the hex/dec code?

Thanks

Comment: It is not an icon, just a character like any other. If other characters like ő work, this one will too.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply escape the unicode value, so that you would not have to save the file in UTF-8 format. Remember to include `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your HTML file's `head`. The `meta` tag will let the user's browser know that we are working with UTF-8. You could also put the actual character (`◹`) as the `content` value, however you would need to ensure that you save the file in UTF-8 format, as well as including the `meta` tag in your HTML's `head` section.

```css
span::before {
 content:'\25F9';
}
```

```html
<span>Test</span>
```